# c libcurl CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS strange error

Tags: c

i'm a quite new c developer and I have a little trouble with libcurl. I searched a lot in the net before but i didn't managed to find an answer working for me.

This is pure c, no ++.

I have this code and the request is failing

```
char * write_url(MyData data)
{
  char *field = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));

  if (strcmp(data.sensorName,"Temperature")==0){
      sprintf(field,"&temperature=%.2f",data.measure);
   }

  CURL *curl;
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1/");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, field);
  curl_easy_perform(curl);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

But if I change

```
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, field);
```

for

```
char *data="&temperature=20"; 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
```

It's working. 
But I want to pass the data through that funcion!

Thanks!

Comment: Try printing the variable `field` after your if. What is it's content? What happens when the condition in the if is not true? Then `field` is not initialized. You should initialize it at least with empty string.

Comment: If strcmp fails field is not initialized causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

malloc() will not initialize the memory, therefore you have to do it. But if the if statement isn't taken the memory remains uninitialized. Do this in the else part of the code:

```
if (strcmp(data.sensorName,"Temperature")==0)
{
     sprintf(field,"&temperature=%.2f",data.measure);
}
else
{
    strcmp(field,"Unknown") ;
}
```

And free the memory when you are done:

```
free(field) ;
```

Also note that the libcurl calls always return an error value, use it.

```
curl = curl_easy_init();    //no error checking is perform in your code
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1/");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```